# Не отключается тачпад на ноутбуке

Tags: ноутбук, asus, тач

Доброго времени суток. Ноутбук ASUS N53SM, ОС Windows 7. Не отключается тачпад, всевозможные методы перепробовал:

1. Горячими клавишами Fn+... все буквы клавиатуры перепробовал.
2. Удалял драйвер i8042, так нет, при запуске ОС он самостоятельно восстанавливался.
3. В реестре `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\i8042prt` пробовал менять значения переменных во всех вложенных разделах, и, после перезагрузки ноутбука - безрезультатно.
4. На английских форумах читал что драйвер `Synaptics` может включать/отключать тачпад, но он не устанавливается: `Произошла ошибка. Устройство Synaptics не найдено.`.

Какие ещё варианты есть? Может, я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: несколько месяцев с этим тачпадом копаюсь. среди интернет паутины решений не нашёл. помогите

Comment: Физически его отключите путем отсоединения соответствующего шлейфа.

Comment: @L'Esperanza, попробуйте отсюда взять драйвера (Pointing Device): https://www.asus.com/ru/support/Download/3/271/0/10/AgfhFhxrh7GzxnrX/30

Comment: @insolor, спасибо!! Помогло! Тачпад теперь отключается через Панель управления -> Мышь -> Touchpad -> Отключение при подсоединении внешней USB-мыши. Только драйвер скачал с другого сайта, т.к. указанная ссылка не работает. Вот: http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/asus/laptops-desktops/n53sm/1353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачал драйвера http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/asus/laptops-desktops/n53sm/1353, подошли. После их установки и перезагрузки ОС нужно зайти в Панель управления -> Мышь -> Touchpad и поставить галочку "Отключение при подсоединении внешней USB мыши".